# Vectorized Flag Assignment in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a dataframe with observations possessing a number of codes. I want to compare the codes present in a row with a list. If any codes are in that list, I wish to flag the row. I can accomplish this using the `itertuples` method as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'cd1' : ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3','abc4','abc5'],
                    'cd2' : ['abc3','abc4','abc5','abc6',''],
                    'cd3' : ['abc10', '', '', '','']})

code_flags = ['abc1','abc6']

# initialize flag column
df['flag'] = 0

# itertuples method

for row in df.itertuples():
    if any(df.iloc[row.Index, 1:4].isin(code_flags)):
       df.at[row.Index, 'flag'] = 1
```

The output correctly adds a `flag` column with the appropriate flags, where 1 indicates a flagged entry.

However, on my actual use case, this takes hours to complete. I have attempted to vectorize this approach using `numpy.where`.

```
df['flag'] = 0 # reset
df['flag'] = np.where(any(df.iloc[:,1:4].isin(code_flags)),1,0)
```

Which appears to evaluate everything the same. I think I'm confused on how the vectorization treats the index. I can remove the semicolon and write `df.iloc[1:4]` and obtain the same result.

Am I misunderstanding the `where` function? Is my indexing incorrect and causing a `True` evaluation for all cases? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `np.where((df.iloc[:,1:4].isin(code_flags)).any(1),1,0)
`

Comment: This is cleaner in addition to accomplishing the task. I had some additional issues with my real dataset as my equivalent of code flags  was a series rather than a list. tolist() fixed that. Barring any more in-depth explanations (I'm obviously still somewhat a novice with pandas/numpy) I'll except this as an answer if you convert it, @Wen

Comment: Ok Let me made a answer for this , in order to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.where` with `.any` not `any(..)`

```
np.where((df.iloc[:,1:4].isin(code_flags)).any(1),1,0)
```